# How to Passing values Stringify Json to Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('contacts', function ($scope,$http,$log) {

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/get-data')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = function(){
       return angular.fromJson(response.data);   
}

        $log.info(response.data.title);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is my code for Angular JS get values from Nodejs stringify MongoDB.

```
[{"_id":"599498fdee5a447417e09e6e","title":"Notice: Undefined index: tx Paypal response API","content":"dssfsd","author":"f","__v":0},{"_id":"5994c1b2cc72e67c229def07","title":"Notice: Undefined index: tx Paypal response API","content":"dssfsd","author":"sdfsdfsfgsd","__v":0}]
```

How to pass this values for one table in AngularJS?

Dont show any values in AngularJS

Comment: response.data.title is wrong try response.data[0].title

Comment: in your example the data is an array so you can access directly title needs iterate over it.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco i´m using " <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x._id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.content }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.author  }}</td>
  </tr>"

Comment: what is names ??? provide more data in the question plz.